# How to call OnCellValidating in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have customized DataGridView and I have ovverided function:

```
protected override void OnCellLeave(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnCellLeave(e);
            if (this.PMCellLeave != null)
                this.PMCellLeave(this, e);
            this.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

            //DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs ve = new CancelEventArgs();
            OnCellValidating(DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs;
}
```

I want to call OnCellValidating, because now when I hit Tab in cell CellValueChanged event is called and CellValidating isn't. I have to create DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs but I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: What's the signature of constructor?

Comment: OnCellValidating(DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)

Comment: DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs has no constructor defined

Comment: The constructor is internal. So which function I have to call to raise CellValidating event from DataGridView ? I try this.EndEdit() but without result

Comment: If the constructor is internal, there must be a good reason (not break anything). Do you use the `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` on your `CellValidatingEvent`?

Comment: Ok, I have work around this problem